# Highlight buttons border after pressing them tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using Python in windows and tkinter,
after I'm pressing a button I want it to that his border will be highlighted like the 'ok' button' in a message box window (and after I'm pressing another button he will be highlighted and the other one wont). example:

[image: example:]

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried?

Comment: I Have used takefocus=0 just to make the gray border go away after pressing a button and now I want the button to be highlighted after pressing it, how do I enjoy both worlds?, by the way the buttons that I'm using are from 'ttk'

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Actual code is much more useful than a description of code.

Comment: why don't you use the `.config()` method to configure the button's attributes after creating it?

Comment: Because its a ttk button so there is that much I can config, but if u got an idea what to config in there I will be grateful